# Apply different QSS stylesheet for custom QT class

Tags: qt, qt5, qtstylesheets

I am using a qss stylesheet for my gui. It works well but I would like to define a different style sheet for my custom widget. 
By example, `QPushbutton`'s style works well but I would like to apply a different style for `MyQPushButton` (extends from QPushButton).

I tried something like this :

```
MyQPushButton
{
    color: #dcdcdc;
    // some code here
}

QPushButton
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    // some code here
}
```

But `QPushButton`'s style has been applied on `MyQPushButton`.
How to override this behavior ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define multiple styles for pushbutton control Qt Widgets stylesheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572082/define-multiple-styles-for-pushbutton-control-qt-widgets-stylesheets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to style a specific element in your project, you can use it like that;

```
QPushButton#MyQPushButton
{
    color: #dcdcdc;
    // some code here
}
```

I assume that, you've already named your new `QPushButton` object as `MyQPushButton`, you can name an element like this;

```
QPushButton* myButton = new QPushButton;
myButton->setObjectName("MyQPushButton");
```

Without naming your element, you can't access it to give it a overrided style.

Comment: I don't know why is that answer is accepted but if you want multiple buttons in a row it will fail

Answer (score 6):

***Ozan Yurtsever*'s answers works but is bad practice.**
You should not use object names for stylesheet, except if you want to style a very unique widget in your application. It is prone to error and more verbose.

Qt stylesheets already allows what you want by default, you can overwrite the style for subclasses (see the end of [this part of the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution)).
As said in the doc, the order of declarations in the stylesheet matters, so your stylesheet should be :

```
QPushButton
{
    color: #b1b1b1;
    // some code here
}
MyQPushButton
{
    color: #dcdcdc;
    // some code here
}
```

Otherwise the style of `QPushButton` will override the style of `MyQPushButton` because `MyQPushButton` is also a `QPushButton`.

It is also possible to limit the scope of your style to the class only and not the subclasses with `.QPushButton { /*some code*/ }`, see [the doc about selectors](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

One last tip, I had issues with stylesheet not working for subclass, check if you did not forget the `Q_OBJECT` macro in the subclass.

Comment: For an unknown reason, your solution does not work
I added MyQPushButton after QPushButton stuff in qss, QObject macro exist ...

Comment: This very simple code works for me (Qt 5.9 but I remember it worked for 4.8 too) : `ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(new QPushButton("QPushButton"));
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(new MyQPushButton("MyQPushButton"));    qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { color: blue; } MyQPushButton { color: red; }");` Except for the Q_OBJECT macro or the way you apply the stylesheet, I don't see what could go wrong. You have no other stylesheet rules that could override those ?

Comment: You can check this answer that works and try to see what is different in your case : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45572455/6165833

Comment: Your solution that overrides default styles is bad practice too