# Styling a custom QWidget

Tags: qt, qt5

In qtcreator i have a mainwindow containing the `centralWidget` of `QWidget` type, and another `QWidget`.

Styling these two `QWidget` is as easy as it gets, in my `stylesheet.css` :

```
QWidget#centralWidget{
    background-color:pink;
}

#nestedWidget{
    background-color:salmon;
    border-radius:20%;
}
```

Now i want to promote `nestedWidget` to a class that inherits from QWidget :

```
class newWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...
}
```

I also promote `nestedWidget` to the type of newWidget in qtcreator.

My problem is that `nestedWidget` is not styled accordingly (it has no style) when it is a `newWidget`, while it is correctly styled when it is a `QWidget`.

How can i fix it so it is correctly styled wether it is a `QWidget` or a `newWidget` ?

Comment: newWidgetObj->setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color:salmon; border-radius:20%; }");

Comment: Can this be done directly in the stylesheet.css though ? this is way more maintainable.

Comment: https://forum.qt.io/topic/88725/how-to-set-qtabbar-by-objectname-in-qss/2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply different QSS stylesheet for custom QT class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706489/apply-different-qss-stylesheet-for-custom-qt-class)

Comment: It should work actually. Qt stylesheet applies to subclasses too, except if you use the class selector `.SomeClass { ... }` instead of the classic type selector ([see the doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)). Something must be wrong somewhere, did you run qmake again?